# What is the composition and strength of the First Order's navy?

Tags: star-wars, first-order

In *The Last Jedi* we see some of the First Order's naval forces, including:

- [*Mandator IV*-class Siege Dreadnought](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mandator_IV-class_Siege_Dreadnought)
- [*Mega*-class Star Dreadnought](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mega-class_Star_Dreadnought)
- [*Resurgent*-class Star Destroyers](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Resurgent-class_Star_Destroyer) (maybe a dozen of them)
- Other smaller craft (e.g. TIE fighters)

Based on my research on Wookieepedia only one *Mega*-class Star Dreadnought was built, but I couldn't find much information about how many *Mandator IV*-class Siege Dreadnoughts and *Resurgent*-class Star Destroyers the First Order had. Do the various supplemental sources have any more information?

**Do the First Order's fleets seen in *The Last Jedi* constitute the bulk of the navy, or are they just a small portion of the naval forces?**

I am primarily interested in learning the strength of the First Order's navy in capital ships during the events of *The Last Jedi*.